FOSS tool to extract tables from PDF
I am looking for a FOSS tool to extract tables from a PDF document.
The standard solution has long been Tabula, but it looks like it is getting little maintenance, is incompatible with modern Java versions, and having to run a local web server is not a particular nice solution either.
The library that powers Tabula, tabula-java, is available separately and could theoretically be incorporated into any PDF tool, as long as it is written in Java, can run Java libraries or is written in a language for which Tabula provides language bindings.
Is anyone aware of a desktop application that is under a FOSS license and incorporates the Tabula library? Alternatively, any FOSS desktop application which is capable of extracting tables from a PDF file?

Have a look at stirling-pdf.  FOSS. Has myriad of extraction possibilities.  Have no idea if it uses tabula libs.
